# Wall Painting Equipment / material

Tags: painting

I am attempting to paint a room in my house for the first time.  I have read the article 
[How do I prepare an already painted wall for new paint?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1380/how-to-prepare-an-already-painted-wall-for-new-paint)

Now i need to know what are the equipment and material I need to do a good job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congrats on joining the world of DIY.  I'll give you a short simple answer, but I think you need to talk with a knowledgeable sales person at your paint store for specific details.

The basics will be drop cloths for the floor, good grade painters tape to mask out your trims, a good grade 2 or 3 inch Purdy brush to edge out around trim and along ceiling, a cut in bucket, a paint tray, roller handle with short extension and a good grade 3/8 inch roller cover.  Good luck

Comment: Rags... you'll need rags... sometimes lots of rags!  Moist rags work well for those Oops! moments.

Answer (score 1):

How big of a room? If it's fairly large, I'd suggest getting a power roller. They allow you to draw paint directly from the can and have it pumped to the roller head saving you the hassle of constantly having to go back to the paint tray.

Otherwise, there's not a whole lot to it. Get some good primer, pay for some good paint, and use good quality rollers and brushes.

Or, if you want to use it as an excuse to get some new toys, splurge for a nice larger compressor and get an air paint sprayer.

Comment: Its quite sad that i cannot indicate 2 answers are correct.  Thanks to you guys i feel more confident to dive in and get painting.