# Should I sand painted drywall before I repaint it?

Tags: drywall, painting, sanding

Should I sand the existing paint on my drywall before a re-paint?  If yes, what sanding paper grit should I use? Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if you should sand the paint on the wall before re-painting?

Comment: Yes. Sanding the paint.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/88741/23295

Comment: We don't sand paint unless you ask us to but we will gladly charge you more money for an unnecessary step. Sponge mop and TSP.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what the finish is that the current paint has. It also assumes that the new paint is compatible to the purpose. ( you are not using automotive paint on a wall of your home. Forgive me if I am too assumptive. People will do very odd things.)

If the current finish has a sheen that is flat, eggshell, or matt finish then no sanding is needed.

If the finish is gloss or perhaps even semi-gloss then a light scuff may be in order.  For those type of finishes I just use a [scuffing pad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0038D35YO) . I use fine or very fine. Then wipe the wall down with a damp towel.

You are then ready to paint.

Answer (score 0):

Sanding (roughing the surface) never harms and it always helps.

The new paint adhesion will be better, and all the handprints (fat) will be removed.